# Using Android Facebook SDK 3.0 Within Android Service

Tags: android, facebook, service

I am looking for an example of how to use the new Facebook SDK 3.0 methods to request a graph path and have the JSON results returned within a Service. The examples that I have found so far are for Activities, but I run my Facebook queries in the background in services that have no Activity at all. Any examples or links to examples would be appreciated.